# How to read network interface static IP in Java when the interface is down

Tags: java, ip-address, ipv4, network-interface, static-ip-address

On my windows system there are 2 NIC's, each configured to different **static IPs** (Eg: IP_1=170.10.120.1 and IP_2=10.20.30.1) and using the below Java Code I am able to print both the interface IPs to the console.

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
for (NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(nets)) {
System.out.println("netint.isUp()" + netint.isUp());
System.out.println("netint.getInterfaceAddresses()" + netint.getInterfaceAddresses());
Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = netint.getInetAddresses();
System.out.println("Collections.list(inetAddresses)" + Collections.list(inetAddresses));
```

When Network_2 is momentarily down, and executing the above Java code prints only IP_1 to the console but IP_2 is returned empty. Since both have static IPs, even when the Interface_2 is down I have a requirement to retrieve both interface details and print their static IPV4 IPs to the console.

How to achieve this? How can I retrieve both interface's static IPs and print them both to console using Java even when one of the interface is down?

Comment: Surely, if the interface is down, then, by definition it does not have an address ?

Comment: The network interface has static IP address configured. So when network is down or if the LAN cable is just removed, under adapter settings still the interface IPV4 IP can be seen in the interface properties.

Comment: Is there any way we can get this static IP of the interface which is down from Java?